# Getting null Pointer in Custom view class

Tags: android, android-layout

I am getting null pointer on back press of activity where I have used the custom view. Where am I doing wrong?? Below is my custom view class:

```java
public class PuzzleBoardView extends View implements ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
    public static final int NUM_SHUFFLE_STEPS = 40;
    Comparator<PuzzleBoard> comparator = new PuzzleBoardComparator();
    PriorityQueue<PuzzleBoard> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(9999, comparator);
    private PuzzleActivity activity;
    private PuzzleBoard puzzleBoard;
    private ArrayList<PuzzleBoard> animation;
    private Random random = new Random();
    private Bitmap imgBitmap;

    public PuzzleBoardView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setMinimumWidth(50);
        activity = (PuzzleActivity) context;
        animation = null;
    }

    public void initialize(final Bitmap imageBitmap, Activity parent) {
        final int width = getWidth();
        imgBitmap = imageBitmap;
        Log.d("PuzzleBoardView", "initialize: width=== " + width);

        addOnAttachStateChangeListener(new OnAttachStateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onViewAttachedToWindow(View v) {
                Log.d("PuzzleBoardView", "onViewAttachedToWindow=== " + width);
                puzzleBoard = new PuzzleBoard(imgBitmap, getWidth());
                shuffle();
            }

            @Override
            public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(View v) {
                Log.d("PuzzleBoardView", "onViewDetachedFromWindow=== ");
                onDetachedFromWindow();

            }
        });
    }

    public void clearView() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Log.d("TAG", "onDraw: =====");
        if (puzzleBoard != null) {
            Log.d("TAG", "onDraw:111 =====");

            if (animation != null && animation.size() > 0) {
                puzzleBoard = animation.remove(0);
                puzzleBoard.draw(canvas);
                if (animation.size() == 0) {
                    animation = null;
                    puzzleBoard.reset();
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(activity, "Solved! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();


                } else {
                    this.postInvalidateDelayed(500);
                }
            } else {
                puzzleBoard.draw(canvas);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        Log.d("PuzzleBoardView", "onDetachedFromWindow=== ");
        getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
    }

    public void shuffle() {
        if (animation == null && puzzleBoard != null) {
// Do something. Then:
            ArrayList<PuzzleBoard> boards;
            for (int i = 0; i <= NUM_SHUFFLE_STEPS; i++) {
                boards = puzzleBoard.neighbours();
                puzzleBoard = boards.get(random.nextInt(boards.size()));
            }
            puzzleBoard.reset();
            invalidate();
            queue.clear();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (animation == null && puzzleBoard != null) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    if (puzzleBoard.click(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
                        invalidate();
                        if (puzzleBoard.resolved()) {
/*Toast toast = Toast.makeText(activity, "Congratulations!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.show();*/
                            activity.puzzleSolved();
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
            }
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    public void solve() {
        puzzleBoard.steps = 0;
        puzzleBoard.previousBoard = null;
        queue.add(puzzleBoard);
        PuzzleBoard prev = null;
        ArrayList<PuzzleBoard> solution = new ArrayList<>();
        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            PuzzleBoard lowest = queue.poll();
            if (lowest.priority() - lowest.steps != 0) {
                for (PuzzleBoard toAdd : lowest.neighbours()) {
                    if (!toAdd.equals(prev)) {
                        queue.add(toAdd);
                    }
                }
                prev = lowest;
            } else {
                solution.add(lowest);
                while (lowest != null) {
                    if (lowest.getPreviousBoard() == null) {
                        break;
                    }
                    solution.add(lowest.getPreviousBoard());
                    lowest = lowest.getPreviousBoard();
                }
                Collections.reverse(solution);
                animation = solution;
                invalidate();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public PuzzleBoard getPuzzleBoard() {
        return puzzleBoard;
    }

    public void setPuzzleBoard(PuzzleBoard puzzleBoard) {
        this.puzzleBoard = puzzleBoard;
    }

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        } else {
            getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        }
        Log.d("PuzzleBoardView", "onAttachedToWindow: width=== " + getWidth());

        puzzleBoard = new PuzzleBoard(imgBitmap, getWidth());
        shuffle();
    }
}

class PuzzleBoardComparator implements Comparator<PuzzleBoard> {
    @Override
    public int compare(PuzzleBoard first, PuzzleBoard second) {
        if (first.priority() == second.priority()) {
            return 0;
        } else if (first.priority() < second.priority()) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Exception
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void android.view.View$OnAttachStateChangeListener.onViewDetachedFromWindow(android.view.View)' on a null object reference

Comment: from where your initialize method is being called?

Comment: OnCreate() of an Activity. There i have set onAttachStatechangelistner on puzzleBoardView object

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like below.

```
public PuzzleBoardView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setMinimumWidth(50);
        activity = (PuzzleActivity) context;
        animation = null;
        if(activity!=null)
        initialize();
    }
```

and remove initialize method from onCreate()